# Laravel + Vue JS: Get/store value of Eloquent Model from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, vue.js, vuejs2

I build a SPA with vue.js 2 for the frontend and Laravel as Backend API.
Now I try to implement a validation if the user failed to sign in more than three times.

So I added a column 'login_attempts' (int) for my user's table.
My problem is that I don't know how to **get** the **'login_attempts'** **value** with [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)  in my laravel backend.

Also, I want to **increase/reset** that **value** if further validation of the login attempt has failed/passed.

```
// UserController.php
public function signin(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $email = $request->input('email');

    // Check if login attempts above 3
    // Here I need to get the 'login_attempts' value
    $loginAttempts = App\User::where('email', $email)->value('login_attempts');
    if($loginAttempts >= 3){
       // Response: To many attempts
    }

    try{
        // Some JWT  Auth validation
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // Increase failed login counter
        // $attemptedUser->   <--- Here i need to increase the 'login_attempts' for the user with the email of the login request
        $attemptedUser->save();
    }
    // Some more validation and response
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tweaks to your original code

```
//Here you get the 'login_attempts' value 

$loginAttempts = App\User::where('email', $email)->select('login_attempts')->first();
```

Then in `catch()` as below

...

```
$loginAttempts->login_attempts += 1;
$loginAttempts->save();
```

This will increase the count.

Comment: make sure to reset `login_attempts` to `0` on successful login.